# Можно ли в After Effects эталонную диаграмму получить в кривой Безье для CSS?

Tags: css, svg, css-animation, after-effects

Прошу прощения если вопрос некорректен, первый раз решаю такую задачу, коллега сделала анимацию в Af Ef, я реализую ее с CSS Animation, понял что каждое действие имеет разный  `animation-timing-function` который можно задать с помощью кривой Безье, например: `cubic-bezier( 0.33, 0.15, 0.58, 0.97 )`, вопрос можно ли где то в Af Ef посмотреть эти значения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> каждое действие имеет разный animation-timing-function который можно
> задать с помощью кривой Безье, например: cubic-bezier( 0.33, 0.15,
> 0.58, 0.97 ), вопрос можно ли где то в Af Ef посмотреть эти значения?

Это вряд ли, что в `after-effects` вы сможете найти, что-то подобное
`cubic-bezier( 0.33, 0.15, 0.58, 0.97 )`

Но если у вас есть внешний вид формы кривой Безье, то вы сможете по этому внешнему виду получить нужные цифры, используя [cubic-bezier онлайн генератор](https://cubic-bezier.com/#.24,.01,.58,.97)

Двигайте рычаги управления, добиваясь нужной формы кривой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заодно можете посмотреть прямо там, как будет  выглядеть ускорения, замедления анимации нажав на кнопку **GO**

Comment: там нету ease но есть timeline и хоть и нету cubic-bezier но за то есть возможность вернуться на кадр и повторить эту анимацию кучу раз или сделать задержку

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать, а был бы полезный инструмент

Comment: @MaximLensky ты не совсем точно понял суть ответа,- имея в timeline эталонную форму кривой, смоделировать в генераторе, точно такую же форму кривой, двигая рычаги управления и получить нужный цифры

Comment: он сгенерирует это .... в видео редакторе не нужен ease

Comment: @MaximLensky прочти пожалуйста ещё раз вопрос: **коллега сделала анимацию в Af Ef, я реализую ее с CSS Animation**  Поэтому автору нужны цифры `cubic-bezier`

Comment: можно применяить easing function js